# Xcode UIWebView not changing page with changed URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I'm automatically generating a NSURL based on the distance of a pan gesture on the screen (long story...).  Anyways, I'm having no problem generating the URL.  The URL dynamically changes, and then I have an NSTimer that repeats every second which tells a UIWebView to reload with the new URL.

However, although the URL is reported to be changing, the UIWebView will only show the first URL sent to it. I'm also monitoring the website itself, and it's receiving the first URL every second, opposed to the updated ones.  My code is pretty simple right now, so I'm not sure what I did wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

In ViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property float slicenumber;
@property NSURL *dynamicUrl;
```

In ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *fullURL = @"http://localhost:8080/remote/slicer/slice?view=Green&orientation=Axial&scrollTo=.50&size=native&fmt=png";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
  [self.webView reload];
  self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
  self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
  self.slicenumber=.5;
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateSlice) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];}

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

  self.slicenumber=self.slicenumber+translation.y/350;
  if (self.slicenumber<0) {
    self.slicenumber=0;
  }
  if (self.slicenumber>1) {
    self.slicenumber=1;
  }
  self.sliceloc.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",self.slicenumber];
  NSString *fullURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/remote/slicer/slice?view=Green&orientation=Axial&scrollTo=%.2f&size=native&fmt=png",self.slicenumber];
  self.dynamicUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[fullURL2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
  NSLog(@"urlString = %@",self.dynamicUrl);}

- (void)UpdateSlice {
  [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.dynamicUrl]];
  [self.webView reload];}
```

Thanks a lot!  Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Not solving your problem, but on a general note: you should not use a timer for this. Just call "updateSlices" from "handlePan:" (and only when the slicenumber changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[self.webView reload]` - will reload the **current** page.  This is probably happening before the loadRequest has finished.
Try removing this line.

Also, @joern's comment is correct; the 'event' is the user making a pan gesture. Lose the timer.

Comment: What is limiting your bacon?

Comment: Haha, unfortunately "Unlimited Bacon" was taken. So I decided to be a realist instead of an idealist.